# want to insert statement in a loop in teradata

Tags: teradata

I'm inserting data into table from another table using below query in Teradata and I want to run this statement until table reaches 20GB. So I want to run below statement in a loop to achieve that. However I written one but it's giving query invalid error when I'm trying to execute. Could you please help me as I'm new to Teradata. Thanks.

```
insert into schema1.xyx select * from schema2.abc;
```

Comment: begin
declare x integer default 0;
set x=x+1
if (x is not null) then
while (x < 1000000000) do
insert into schema1.xyx select * from schema2.abc;
set x=X+1;
end while;
end if;
end;

Answer (score 0):

if/loop/etc. are only allowed in Stored Procedures.

Looping a billion times will be quite inefficient (and will result in much more than 20GB). Better check the current size of table abc from dbc.TableSizeV, calculate how many loops you need and then cross join.

```
insert into schema1.xyx 
select t.* 
from schema2.abc AS t
cross join
 (        -- calculated number of loops
   select top 100000 *
   -- any table with a large number of rows
   from sys_calendar_calendar
 );
```

But much easier is using sampling.
Calculate the number of rows needed and then

```
insert into schema1.xyx 
select * 
from schema2.abc
sample with replacement 100000000;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.